# Adding an IMAP account without saving emails locally in Mail 7.0

Tags: mail.app, data-synchronization, macos, imap

I want to add an IMAP-account to Mail. 
Since I've used this account for many years, it contains thousands of emails and archive folders, and I really don't want to fill up my SSD with that.

I couldn't find a way to limit synchronization to a certain time frame or specific folders (I guess that's not really the concept of IMAP).

I found out that there used to be a "Don't keep copies of any messages" checkbox in Mail's preferences, so emails would not be stored locally.
I would be completely satisfied with this solution, however, in Mail 7.0 this option was removed (which I don't understand, seems like such a basic function to me).

Does anybody have a solution for this?

Suggestions for alternative software are welcome as well (in case there's really no way to use Apple Mail without downloading my entire mail history).

Answer (score 1):

Please check this [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/42780/is-there-a-way-to-limit-mail-to-only-keep-the-last-50-mails).

One way to save space is to exclude attachments from download.
I think you have to uncheck: Account->Advanced->Automatically download all attachments

Comment: [This should have been one comment, but it won't let me edit the first one anymore]

I already excluded attachments, but still it takes a lot of space. 
Permanently deleting older messages (as suggested in your link) is no solution since I want to keep them on the server. Due to IMAP synchronization, every email I delete on my computer is deleted on the server as well.